# Why am I getting a 403 for Google AdSense on my verified site?

Tags: ads, http-status-code-403, adsense, robots.txt, google-ads-api

AdSense shows that it is verified. I have waited about 10 hours and even the placeholder for ads is not appearing.

AdSense does not show any Policy violations, Crawler errors, or messages.

I found this while inspecting the headers for the adsense request: `Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`

Complete text of the request and status message:

```
Request URL:https://googleads.g.doubleclick.net/pagead/ads?client=ca-pub-****************&format=1200x90&output=html&h=90&slotname=3349281912&adk=2375655327&adf=3025194257&w=1200&afmt=auto&lmt=1494458991&rafmt=1&flash=25.0.0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvling.at%2F&resp_fmts=3&wgl=1&dt=1494459018567&bpp=20&bdt=84&fdt=23&idt=45&shv=r20170508&cbv=r20170110&saldr=aa&correlator=969628337021&frm=20&ga_vid=1590241153.1493524169&ga_sid=1494459019&ga_hid=2035244233&ga_fc=0&pv=2&iag=3&icsg=2&nhd=1&dssz=2&mdo=0&mso=0&u_tz=-300&u_his=4&u_java=0&u_h=1080&u_w=1920&u_ah=1050&u_aw=1920&u_cd=24&u_nplug=5&u_nmime=7&adx=0&ady=0&biw=1249&bih=984&eid=575144605%2C137237720&oid=3&rx=0&eae=0&fc=16&brdim=0%2C0%2C0%2C0%2C1920%2C0%2C1920%2C1050%2C1249%2C984&vis=1&rsz=%7C%7CeE%7C&abl=CS&ppjl=u&pfx=0&fu=144&bc=1&ifi=1&xpc=Mf0j8p1Icb&p=http%3A//vling.at&dtd=69
Request Method:GET
Status Code:403 
Remote Address:216.58.208.98:443
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

What does this mean? Whatever it means is behind my problem.

This is the specific section of adsense script that is failing.

```
.write(c)},du=function(a,b,c){var d=E;b.src=wr(a);a=Ir(b);return cu(d,a,c)},gu=function(a,b,c,d){var e=E;b.src=wr(a);a=Ir(b);if(e.google_native_ad_template)return eu(e,a,c,d);if(c=yf(e)){e=Gp(M(),e);b={native_ad_template:e};if(e)return fu(c,a,d,b);a=Fp("AD_TEMPLATE_NOT_FOUND");e=a.code;a=a.message;window.console&&window.console.error&&window.console.error(e,a);if(b=b.native_ad_template){var f={status:"ERROR",errCode:e,errMessage:a,template:b},g=M();try{if(D.createEvent){var h=
```

Note that I DO INDEED have an AD Template specified.
Any help, or direction on solving this is most welcome..

Thanks!

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?

Answer (score 7):

[J. DiPasquale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7986794/j-dipasquale) [said right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43702343/why-am-i-getting-a-403-for-google-adsense-on-my-verified-site/43902876#43902876), you need to make sure if ad serving is enabled on your website. If you want to publish ads on your website you should:

1. Login to your AdSense
2. Go to My Ads > Other Products > Submit > Fill in the verification form.
3. Wait for your website to be verified.

Comment: @ronald8192 sorry, my answer was a bit wrong, now its corrected. "My Publishments" was actually "My Ads"

Comment: Is this replacing the My Sites option under Settings?

Answer (score 0):

in my experience, i've placed popcash and another ads on my site before google adsense review, even i removed it and my site was approved by adsense, i must request google to review my site on google webmaster tools.

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/abusive-experience

[image]

Answer (score -5):

Try disabling Ad-Blocking extensions from your browser

Comment: It is not an adblock issue.